# Symfony2 One Entity/Model, Many Modules

Tags: symfony

I have a question about the architecture of a Symfony2 project.

Is there any particular way to have such a project's architecture:

```
/app
/src
--/Admin
----/DefaultBundle
------/Controller
------/DependencdyInjection
------/Entity
------/Form
------/Resources
------/...
--/Front
----/DefaultBundle
------/Controller
------/DependencdyInjection
------/Entity
------/Form
------/Resources
------/...
/vendor
/www
```

and to use one Entity class for both of the modules (Admin/Front) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony2 follows this convention:

```
/src/OrganizationName/SomeBundle/Controller [Entity / Resource / etc. ]
```

so you should provide 2 bundles [e.g. `FrontendBundle`, `AdminBundle`] inside a common `YourAwesomeOrganization` folder.

Then you can share classes between the two as usual, e.g.:

```
<?php
use YourAwesomeOrganization\FrontendBundle\Entity\User;
use YourAwesomeOrganization\BackendBundle\Form\Type\LoginFormType;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse. Just create those bundles like any others and enable both of them in you `AppKernel`.

Answer (score -1):

Something I understood in the work process with Sf2/Zf2 is that You could/must use
"service manager" for sharing different functionalities between bundles/modules:
Sf2: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html
Zf2: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.service-manager.intro.html

Comment: The Entity classes, as well as other classes can be referenced and inherited without services, just use PHP 5.3 namespaces